# Is there a family of Haskell functions for sequencing tuples of applicatives?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Is there a standard function, or family of functions, for sequencing tuples of applicatives, as a generalization of `sequenceA`? Like the following, except for all reasonable tuple lengths:

```hs
sequence3TupleA :: Applicative f => (f a1, f a2, f a3) -> f (a1, a2, a3)
```

I believe this should be possible to implement (it is for the applicatives I'm working with anyway).

I found [`SequenceT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Sequence.html) from `Data.Tuple.Sequence`, but it appears to require a monad and also it doesn't seem to actually contain the sequence function (I am probably misreading the documentation somehow).

Comment: a general form is this one `f (a,b,c) = pure (,,) <*> a <*> b <*> c`. It can be extended to any tuple

Comment: Given that all the instances of `SequenceT` are defined in terms of `return` and `ap`, I'd say that package simply predates the `Applicative` class. Replace `return` with `pure` and `ap` with `<*>`, and you have precisely what @Ismor suggests.

Comment: `SequenceT` is a type class the defines the method `sequenceT`, which is basically the function you are looking for.

Comment: Using the lens library you have the combinator `sequenceAOf each` which does what you want, except the elements of the tuple must have the same type: `Applicative f => (f a, f a, f a) -> f (a, a, a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SequenceT` typeclass and its method `sequenceT` from the `tuple` package does indeed do what you're looking for. Unfortunately, this package seems to have been abandoned since 2014, before the `Applicative` typeclass was introduced, so only works with `Monad` instances. An [issue](https://github.com/augustss/tuple/issues/4) to sort this has been open since 2017, and an associated [pull request](https://github.com/augustss/tuple/pull/5) was closed by the contributor.

As @lsmor mentions in a comment, this function is not difficult, its definition is:

```
sequence3TupleA (a, b, c) = (,,) <$> a <*> b <*> c
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood what the `sequenceT` method was because the source links in the documentation are broken. Looking [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/src/Data.Tuple.Sequence.html) I see that it's what I want, and it does match my special-case implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are a bit a "pain" in Haskell, because the type is not recursive, producing functions requires to implement this for all tuples. There have been proposals that `(a, b, c)` for example is *syntactical sugar* for `(a, (b, c))` and that only 2-tuples really exist, or at least from a type-system point-of-view. This is to some extend what a `HList` is doing.

The pattern that [@Ismor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74528578/is-there-a-family-of-haskell-functions-for-sequencing-tuples-of-applicatives#comment131564477_74528578) described can however be implemented through template Haskell. I found the question quite fascinating, and implemented this for the [`tuple-append` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-append): it defines a typeclass `SequenceTuple` that implements a `sequenceTupleA` and `sequenceTupleA_` that implements these for tuples up to length 62, since this is the upperbound of GHC for the number of elements in a tuple, although very likely using such large tuples will never be necessary.